# Hibernate - second level association

Tags: java, hibernate

Let's say I have table foo, table bar, and table zoo.
foo has a member bar and there is a one to one relationship between them.
bar has a list and there is a one to many relationship between them.

the list is not initialized automatically when bar is read (ie it is lazy)
Using hql I would like to get a list of the foo objects with zoo initialized in bar.

so something on the lines of:

```
select f from Foo f
left join fetch f.bar.zoo
```

this obviously throws an exception and I get that it's because the owner being returned is Foo and not Bar.  Nonetheless I need Foo and not Bar and I need zoo to be initialized.  Is there a way to do this in one query?

Thanks
Jill

Comment: My HQL's rusty but that actually looks OK to me.  You should post at least the stack trace from the exception.

Answer (score 0):

The following should work:

```
FROM Foo f
  LEFT JOIN FETCH f.bar b
  LEFT JOIN FETCH b.zoos
```

Comment: tried but now I get a null pointer exception. on the second left join fetch.

Comment: @Jill Please show mappings allowing to reproduce. I tried with some entities and I get the expected result.